# Searching with multiple keywords

Tags: php, mysql, search

if that would be my database

```
+---------------------------------+
|ID|Name|Department|EMail|Location|
+---------------------------------+
|3 |Sivi|Kitchen   |si@gm|Home    |
|4 |Mini|Office    |mi@gm|Garden  |
|5 |Alba|Office    |al@gm|Hom     |
+---------------------------------+
```

I also have a search field where your currently able to search with 1 keyword through the whole database.
e.g I enter `Sivi` I get the ouptut

`|3 |Sivi|Kitchen   |si@gm|Home    |`

if I search just for example `Off` I would get the rows:

```
|4 |Mini|Office    |mi@gm|Garden  |
|5 |Alba|Office    |al@gm|Hom     |
```

Current SQL Statement:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM form WHERE CONCAT(ID, Name, Department, Email, Location) LIKE '%".$search."%'";`

However I want to be able indicate with each space made a new "keyword" which again searches through the whole database. e.g I search for `'Siv Home'` I want to get the output

`|3 |Sivi|Kitchen   |si@gm|Home    |`

If I search for `'Mi Offi'` I get the row:

```
|4 |Mini|Office    |mi@gm|Garden  |
```

Because if I currently search for `'Mi Offi'` I get no output.

You probably have to split the string you get from the textfield by every space made and then search with each splitted string through the database, however I have no clue what the most efficient way would be to do this.

Comment: above one should be your table not your database

Comment: Split words, generate multiple conditions.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: you will have to make all possible condition in where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first get the string and explode it. make condition as require.

```
    $inputdata='Mi Offi';
    $search=explode(' ',$inputdata);
    $cond=' 1=1 ';
    foreach($search as $i=>$data){
      if($i==0){
      $cond .=" and (CONCAT(ID, Name, Department, Email, Location)    LIKE '%".$data."%')` ";
      }else {
       $cond .=" OR (CONCAT(ID, Name, Department, Email, Location)    LIKE '%".$data."%')` ";
      }
    }
$sql = "SELECT * FROM form WHERE".$cond ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would approach something like this:

```
$sOutput        = '';
$sSearchString  = 'search1 search2 search 3';

$aSearchTerms   = explode(" ", $sSearchString);


if($aSearchTerms){

    foreach ($aSearchTerms as $iPos => $sTerm) {
        if($sOutput != '') $sOutput .= " OR ColName ";
        $sOutput .= "LIKE '%".$sTerm."%' ";
    }
}


echo $sOutput;
exit;
```